# MVC Linq query returning an inherited Entity's ID, but the Entity is null. How do I .Include() TPH members?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have an MVC C# application using Razor Views.  I have just implemented Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) and have run into an issue where I cannot .Include() the inherited Entity.

## Project Details View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FundingOpportunity.FundingProgram.FundingAgency.Name)
```

**When I attempt to show the contents of FundingAgency, it is always null.  I can also modify the controller to .include FundingAgency, but it still comes up null.**

## Modified Project Controller:

```
    // GET: /Project/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var projectList = db
                            .Projects
                            .Include(p => p.FundingOpportunity)
                            .Include(p => p.FundingOpportunity.FundingProgram)
                            .Include(p => p.FundingOpportunity.FundingProgram.FundingAgency);

        Project project = projectList.Where(p => p.ID == id).First();

        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(project);
    }
```

Here I have modified the Project Controller to .Include the FundingAgency.  You can see how the FundingAgencyID has a value and that value exists in the database, but the link to the FundingAgency Entity is not there.  *This is only happening with Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) items.*

[image: Showing the null value]

Comment: Can you check and post the generated query, e.g. `var sql = db.Programs.Include(p => p.Agency).ToString();`

Comment: I meant the generated SQL text. Alternatively, are you sure there is no `FundingAgency_Id` column (note the underscore) in the `FundingProgram` database table?

Comment: Absolutely, here you go @Ivan.  
I have uploaded the result of this on Pastebin given it's size: http://pastebin.com/MzTWS2AG

This command was run on the "Modified Project Controller" 
var sql = db.Projects.Include(p => p.FundingOpportunity.FundingProgram.FundingAgency).ToString();

Comment: I don't know if the most recent comment answers your second question or not.  I did attempt to specify ClassID as the key to override the default Class_ID behavior in all Classes.  There should be no underscores in the database tables.  The updated code above shows the actual names, which should make this less confusing.

Comment: Thank you, disregard my previous comment., it was before you posted the SQL. So the SQL is fine, there really seems to be some loading issue, I have to play with it to see what's going on.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Created the sample model and everything works as expected (latest EF6.1.3 if that matters). You might check the `Contact` table if `Discriminator` column is filled correctly, because as you can see from the generated SQL, it's part of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so it's possible to return `null` even if `FundingAgencyID` has a value, but the corresponding record `Discriminator` is not "FundingAgency".

Comment: @IvanStoev, your responses lead directly to me changing my focus from the Controller to the Seed/Migration Files and SQL Tables where I noticed an error.  I have updated this post with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I will post my solution for those searching in the future for a similar issue.*

## Update:

During the Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) migration, the seed/migration file order was moved and this caused the SQL query to return the correct row, then check the Discriminator and that check failed, so it returned null.  This was deceptive because when you step through the process, the ID was not null and that row on the table contained data.

## Solution:

I updated the seed files so that the correct ID range was attached to FundingOpportunity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as shown below.

```
Program program = db.Programs.Where(X => X.ID == id)
                          .Include(p => p.Agency)
                          .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
public class Agency : Contact
{
 -->   public virtual ICollection<Program> Programs { get; set; }
}
```

It should be:

```
public virtual ICollection<FundingProgram> Programs {get; set;}
```

In addition to this, this line of code might be wrong:

```
Program program = programs.Where(X => X.ID == id).First();

if (project == null) // Where does your project come from? Did you mean program?
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code, thank you for noticing those.  The actual code is much more complex and it was simplified to make understanding easier here.  Those two elements were artifacts I missed from the original naming convention.  They have been replaced.